# Android only TWRP starts which doesn't load

Tags: adb, boot, twrp

I've an Samsung Galaxy S7 with Android 7. I tried to updated it with Smart Switch. But after that, the phone ends with an "encryption unsuccessfully" error. I wanted to save my data, so I flashed twrp. But TWRP didn't let me in my Internal Storage. I wanted to format "/data", but it hang over, so I restarted the phone. Now it only boots in the TWRP-Recovery, but it doesn't load (only the loading screen appears). I can't boot into download mode or something else.